# Change dyno size with heroku scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduler, dyno

Is there a way to perform scheduled changes of the dyno type in Heroku (e.g., from hobby to free and vice-versa)?

I have tried heroku scheduler with the command heroku dyno:type but (obviously) it did not work (dyno type did not change from hobby to standard-1x)....

[image]